# JSON return 2 array with 1 element

Tags: php, json

I have this function:

```
public function findFavoriteMerchant($userId) {
  // I grab all the merchant_id from favoriteMerchant where user_id = $userId
  $q = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM favoriteMerchant WHERE user_id = ?");
  $q->bindParam(1, $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);


        if ($q->execute()){

        $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $i = -1;

              foreach ($result as $row) {

              $merchant = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM merchant WHERE merchant_id = ?");
              $merchant->bindParam(1, $row["merchant_id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

                   if ($merchant->execute()){

                       $i++;

                       $merchantArray[$i] = $merchant->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    }
               }        
               return $merchantArray;
         }
}
```

that return this :

```
[
  [ 
    {
        "merchant_id": "17",
        "business_name": "Nails Spa",
        "merchant_first_name": "Jonh ",
        "merchant_last_name": "Lampard",
        "merchant_email": "email@me.com",
        "merchant_address": "123 lampard street",
        "merchant_country": "United States",
        "merchant_city": "San Francisco ",
        "merchant_state": "Dubai",
        "merchant_postalCode": "92",
        "merchant_telephone": "043251653",
        "merchant_industry": "Beauty",
        "merchant_type": "Spa",
        "merchant_service": "other",
        "merchant_lat": "37.804512",
        "merchant_long": "-122.432335"
    }
],
[
    {
        "merchant_id": "19",
        "business_name": "Massage Spa",
        "merchant_first_name": "carl",
        "merchant_last_name": "smith",
        "merchant_email": "email@me.com",
        "merchant_address": "",
        "merchant_country": "United States",
        "merchant_city": "San Francisco ",
        "merchant_state": "Dubai",
        "merchant_postalCode": "92",
        "merchant_telephone": "043278439",
        "merchant_industry": "Beauty",
        "merchant_type": "Spa",
        "merchant_service": "other",
        "merchant_lat": "25.037189",
        "merchant_long": "55.251812"
    }
  ]
]
```

but I would like to get this:

```
[
    {
        "merchant_id": "17",
        "business_name": "Nails Spa",
        "merchant_first_name": "Jonh ",
        "merchant_last_name": "Lampard",
        "merchant_email": "email@me.com", 
      // and so on....
```

****UPDATE****

```
    $merchant =  new Merchant();
    echo json_encode($merchant->findFavoriteMerchant($userId),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

print r returns:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [merchant_id] => 17
            [business_name] => Massage Spa
            [merchant_first_name] => Jonh 
            [merchant_last_name] => Lampard
            [merchant_email] => email@me.com
            [merchant_address] => 123 lampard street
            [merchant_country] => United States
            [merchant_city] => San Francisco 
            [merchant_state] => Dubai
            [merchant_postalCode] => 92
            [merchant_telephone] => 043251653
            [merchant_industry] => Beauty
            [merchant_type] => Spa
            [merchant_service] => other
            [merchant_lat] => 37.804512
            [merchant_long] => -122.432335
            [merchant_userName] => Aviation 
            [password] => cfc10a708f01fe27750e3be246ca1daa
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [merchant_id] => 19
            [business_name] => Angsana Spa
            [merchant_first_name] => carl
            [merchant_last_name] => smith
            [merchant_email] => email@me.com
            [merchant_address] => 
            [merchant_country] => United States
            [merchant_city] => San Francisco 
            [merchant_state] => Dubai
            [merchant_postalCode] => 92
            [merchant_telephone] => 043278439
            [merchant_industry] => Beauty
            [merchant_type] => Spa
            [merchant_service] => other
            [merchant_lat] => 25.037189
            [merchant_long] => 55.251812

        )

)
```

I tried several approaches but I don't get it

Comment: update the question to include the part where you build the final array you do `json_encode` on it

Comment: also, if you could add a `print_r($merchantArray[$i]);` inside the loop and update the question with the output that would be great

Comment: do you want only one result? maybe it is data problem. is it sure that the user has one favorite merchant ?

Comment: user in the database has 2 favourite merchant. I need both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the individual elements from the return of `fetchAll` since it returns an array.

Use a simple `foreach` to populate your final array.
Everything else stays the same, return `$merchantArray`, `json_encode` it then print it out.

```
$results = $merchant->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $result){
    $merchantArray[$i] = $result;
}
```

Comment: this also works! I think this is a more correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

$merchant->fetchAll() returns an array. you added an array to result array, two times.  take a first item or use foreach loop.

Comment: `$data =  $merchant->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$merchantArray[$i] = $data[0];` I did this and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @wafe, I selected the other answer because I think it's more complete and help other people to understand what to do. Thanks anyway +1

Comment: @mat I agree :) i am on moblie, so my answer is not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You could either extract the first row from the result of the second query

```
$merchantArray[$i] = $merchant->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];
```

Or you could use a JOIN to get all of the information at once

```
public function findFavoriteMerchant($userId) {
  // grab all merchant information from merchant where the merchant_id matches from favoriteMerchant where user_id = $userId
  $q = $this->_db->prepare("
    SELECT merch.*
    FROM favoriteMerchant AS fav
    INNER JOIN merchant merch ON fav.merchant_id = merch.merchant_id
    WHERE user_id = ?");
  $q->bindParam(1, $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if ($q->execute()){
      $merchantArray = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $merchantArray;
    }
}
```